# How to remove/delete a game object

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do you make an object that can kill/remove itself? e.g.

```js
var bullet = [];
function bullet() {
  this.removeSelf = () => {
    this = false;
  }
}
function setup() {
  bullet[0] = new Bullet();
  bullet[0].removeSelf();
}
setup();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to remove it from the parent array, you need to edit that array. So we can pass the parent into the instance and have the `removeSelf` look for its instance in the parent and `splice` it out.

I also renamed the constructor to `Bullet`.

```js
var bullets = [];

function Bullet(parent) {
  this.removeSelf = () => {
    const index = parent.indexOf(this);
    parent.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

function setup() {
  bullets[0] = new Bullet(bullets);
  bullets[1] = new Bullet(bullets); // Add a second isntance to the array
  bullets[0].removeSelf();
}

setup(); 
console.log(bullets.length) // Should be 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly but if you mean to destroy the object and free the memory then you first need to remove all references to it and then garbage collector will automatically do the job for you.

You're storing a reference to the object in the array so you can do this:
`bullet[0] = null`